# Xamarin ListView Height equal to ContentSize

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've been struggling with this for two days now and still can't seem to get it fixed.. so I hope you guys are able to help me out!

I have a page which has a WebView and a ListView. Both items are able to scroll on it's own, but I do not want that. I want the page to be fully scrollable. 
This means I have to place both objects inside a ScrollView and set the .Height equal to it's contentSize.

For the WebView it was pretty easy, since it has a LoadFinished event I was able to set the Height equal to it's content.

Now I'm writing the ListView and I'm having really trouble with this. Since I am loading my data async from a webservice it seems that the contentsize of the UITableView is always 0 inside my renderer.

```
public class RZNoScrollListViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<RZNoScrollTableView, UITableView>
{
private UITableView _tableView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<RZNoScrollTableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        _tableView = Control as UITableView;
        ResizeView ();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        ResizeView ();
    }

    private async void ResizeView()
    {
        if (_tableView != null) 
        {
            _tableView.LayoutIfNeeded ();
            var contenSizeHeight = _tableView.ContentSize.Height;
            var frame = _tableView.Frame;
            frame.Height = contenSizeHeight;

            _tableView.Frame = frame;

            var listElement = Element as RZNoScrollTableView;
            var bounds = new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle (Element.Bounds.X, Element.Bounds.Y, Element.Bounds.Width, frame.Height);
            await Element.LayoutTo (bounds, listElement.TransitionSpeedMsec, listElement.Easing);
            Element.HeightRequest = bounds.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can reach my goal?

Comment: Are the rows a constant height in the TableView?  It might be easier to just size the table view based on the row height and number of rows.

Comment: No they aren't.. I'm going for Robert's answer since that helps me out  a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the web view in the listviews header. Then the listviews content should virtualize as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Your solution wouldn't help, because I have another view on top which contains an image.

I tried to do what you say (see image below). Red is the image and below that is the ListView with the WebView as header. Problem is that the ListView is now scrollable and the image on top stays static

[See image](http://s22.postimg.org/9k6in1lr5/Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_15_2015_2_25_27_PM.png)